# Which software for statistics and data analytics?

Tags: data-analysis, statistics

I've got a list of products (item name, prices, attributes, description, etc.) in a Mongo DB.

Now I'd like to get some insights like:

> How many products from this group contains the string "green" in attributes?
>
> List the prices for products containing string in item name over time

Which software / language would I use there, if I'd like to visualise the results on a responsive website?
I'm doing easy sums etc. via Python already, generate a JSON from that and display via Chart.js. Now I started reading about panda which might be good for some analytics but I'm wondering whether something like JasperSoft or other BIs would get me to a result quicker/with a smaller learning curve?
(It should always have a JSON or CSV output, so that I can use it in Chart.js - or generate nice dashboards itself)

Comment: Pandas can generate json, csv, excel or actual charts directly.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's quite nice. But it seems as if I have to do a lot of custom coding with Python and I assume Jasper or similar would be faster?

Comment: have you tried Pandas from within a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Looks nice but maybe a bit in a different direction. I had sth. like Piwik in mind.